# MVC can not save data to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save the data to the database that passed from view by using post.
I'm getting no error but its no add the value into database.

my json is look like

```
{
    "Schedule Name": "name1",
    "data1": "a3c1",
    "data2": "a3c1",
    "data3": "a3c1",
    "data4": "a3c1",
    "data5": "a3c1",
    "data6": "a3c1",
    "data7": "a3c1"
}
```

here is my controller

```
public class ScheduleController : Controller
{
    DatabaseContext _db = new DatabaseContext();

    public ActionResult schedule()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Addmore(string list1)
    {
        bool result = true;
        newlist personData;
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        personData = jss.Deserialize<newlist>(list1);
        savv(personData);
        return Content(result.ToString());
    }

    public void savv(newlist nl) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (_db)
            {
                _db.Schedule.Add(nl);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public class newlist
    {
        public string namIDs { get; set; }
        public string aIDs { get; set; }
        public string bIDs { get; set; }
        public string cIDs { get; set; }
        public string dIDs { get; set; }
        public string eIDs { get; set; }
        public string fIDs { get; set; }
        public string gIDs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my db

```
 public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<ScheduleController.newlist> Schedule { get; set; }
```

}

here is my post

```
table_content = JSON.stringify({ 'Schedule Name': def ,'data1':data1 ,'data2':data2,'data3':data3,'data4':data4,'data5':data5,'data6':data6,'data7':data7});
    alert(table_content);
    $.post(url1, {
        jsonData: table_content
    },
    function (data, textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
        if (textStatus != "success") {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

the text Status always return "success" but no value store into database
Anyone can help me? Anythings I miss out on code?

I just use another way to store the value to database

```
public ActionResult Addmore(newlist personData)
    {
        var data1 = "hello";
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Sche values('" + personData.namIDs + "','" + personData.aIDs + "','" + personData.bIDs + "','" + personData.cIDs + "','" + personData.dIDs + "','" + personData.eIDs + "','" + personData.fIDs + "','" + personData.gIDs + "')", con);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sche VALUES('" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "','" + data1 + "')", con);

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i > 0) { result = true; }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return Content(result.ToString());
    }
```

But it still not working for me

even through I type this on code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sche VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)", con);
```

but its still not adding to database
This is not a connection error because this command line can work

string query = "SELECT * FROM Sche";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

Comment: You have so many errors its hard to know where to start. Begin with changing you method to `public ActionResult Addmore(newlist model)`. The in the ajax, use `data: { namIDs: 'abc', aIDs: 'def', cIDs: 'ghi', .... etc },`  - i.e. to match your model properties. The `model` parameter will be bound with the correct values you post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Addmore(newlist personData)
{
    bool result = true;
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    savv(personData);
    return Content(result.ToString());
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Addmore", "Schedule")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ namIDs : 'def' ,aIDs:'data1' ,bIDs :'data2',cIDs :'data3',dIDs :'data4',eIDs :'data5',fIDs :'data6',gIDs:'data7'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name of your action and the post parameter name must be the same. Change `jsonData` to `list1` or vice versa

Answer (score -1):

Personally, i wouldn't use MVC controller and stringify the json as it would change the data type.  Post the data as is and use web API instead.  It has a built in mechanism to parse JSON data

Comment: If just post the data then how the controller receive the data?

Comment: It's best to use web API controller.  Do you know how to create the web API controller?  If not, refer the following link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: MVC also will parse JSON data directly into the model!